# Decode Json from Youtube api on Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, youtube-data-api

I make a call to Youtube API and get this Json:

```
     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/s7-xmHXpuqQxYzDp_wxhm59K4LE\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/pajQ7iBy-7A0V_owifxkw-Kbw-Y\"",
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T23:12:38.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
```

But now I want to parse it and get just 3 nodes:

1. Title
2. Description
3. The url for the default thumbnail

Indeed I get the Json response and can see it on the logs, but when try to parse it every time it fails.

This is my code:

```
final response = await http.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=HEREGOESMYAPIKEY&part=snippet&id=T0Jqdjbed40');

final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
String title  = parsed['items']['snippet']['title'];
print(title);
String description  = parsed['items']['snippet']['description'];
print(description);
String thumbnail  = parsed['items']['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
print(thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be bit late to answer the question.

If you want to learn how to parse complex json data use these articles.

[1. Parsing JSON in the background - Flutter cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing)

and 
[Parsing complex JSON in Flutter- medium.com by Pooja Bhaumik](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51)

FYI - Youtube data api response is in a nested Json format

I used a alternative way, this is not recommended for big applications(I was just playing around with it and this is only for above type json tree)

Use async function to retrieve and parse Json data.

```
final String dataUrl = "YOUR-JSON-URL";

Future<String> getdet() async {

var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(dataUrl), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);

      convertedData = responseBody["items"];

    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to Load Data');
    }
```

> "items " is the array starting point

after that you can use it in a Widget for example

```
Widget recentWidget(){
    return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: convertedData == null ? 0 : recent.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, ) {
              return Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Image.network(recent[index]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"]),
                        new ListTile(                         
                            title: new Text(recent[index]["snippet"]["title"]),
                                subtitle: Text("This is Subtitle"),
                             },
                            dense: true,
                          ),
                      ],
                  ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      )
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying won't work with Dart, this is not javascript. Dart has very strong type system, which is great. You are trying to assign value to a variable you've defined as `String`, but the response you have defined a dynamic, so Dart can't validate the value assignment. Also items is array, there is no such key items->snippet.

The correct way to do this is to create model deinitions, which will handle deserialisation and also will provide convenient way of accessing properties you are interested in.

```
class YoutubeResponse {

  String kind;
  String etag;
  String nextPageToken;

  String regionCode;
  List<Item> items;

  YoutubeResponse(
      {this.kind,
      this.etag,
      this.nextPageToken,
      this.regionCode,
      this.items});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'kind': kind,
        'etag': etag,
        'nextPageToken': nextPageToken,
        'regionCode': regionCode,
        'items': items,
      };

  factory YoutubeResponse.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> YoutubeResponseJson) {

    var list = YoutubeResponseJson['items'] as List;
    List<Item> itemsList = list.map((i) => Item.fromJSON(i)).toList();

    return new YoutubeResponse(
        kind: YoutubeResponseJson['kind'],
        etag: YoutubeResponseJson['etag'],
        nextPageToken: YoutubeResponseJson['nextPageToken'],
        regionCode: YoutubeResponseJson['regionCode'],
        mPageInfo: pageInfo.fromJSON(YoutubeResponseJson['pageInfo']),
        items: itemsList);
  }

}

class Item {
  String kind;
  String etag;
  Id id;
  Snippet snippet;

  Item({this.kind, this.etag, this.id, this.snippet});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'kind': kind,
        'etag': etag,
        'id': id,
        'snippet': snippet,
      };

  factory Item.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> ItemJson) {
    return Item(
      kind: ItemJson['kind'],
      etag: ItemJson['etag'],
      id: Id.fromJSON(ItemJson['id']),
      snippet: Snippet.fromJSON(ItemJson['snippet']),
    );
  }
}

class Snippet {
  String publishedAt;
  String channelId;
  String title;
  String description;
  Thumbnails thumbnails;
  String channelTitle;
  String liveBroadcastContent;

  Snippet(
      {this.publishedAt,
      this.channelId,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.thumbnails,
      this.channelTitle,
      this.liveBroadcastContent});


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'publishedAt': publishedAt,
        'channelId': channelId,
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'thumbnails': thumbnails,
        'channelTitle': channelTitle,
        'liveBroadcastContent': liveBroadcastContent,
      };

  factory Snippet.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> SnippetJson) {


    return Snippet(
      publishedAt: SnippetJson['publishedAt'],
      channelId: SnippetJson['channelId'],
      title: SnippetJson['title'],
      description: SnippetJson['description'],
      thumbnails:  Thumbnails.fromJSON(SnippetJson['thumbnails']) ,
      channelTitle: SnippetJson['channelTitle'],
      liveBroadcastContent: SnippetJson['liveBroadcastContent'],
    );
  }
}

class Medium {
  int height;
  int width;
  String url;

  Medium({this.height, this.width, this.url});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
        'url': url,
      };

  factory Medium.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> MediumJson) {
    return Medium(
      height: MediumJson['height'],
      width: MediumJson['width'],
      url: MediumJson['url'],
    );
  }

}

class High {
  int height;
  int width;
  String url;

  High({this.height, this.width, this.url});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
        'url': url,
      };

  factory High.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> HighJson) {
    return High(
      height: HighJson['height'],
      width: HighJson['width'],
      url: HighJson['url'],
    );
  }

}

class Default {
  int height;
  int width;
  String url;

  Default({this.height, this.width, this.url});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
        'url': url,
      };

  factory Default.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> defaultJson) {
    return Default(
      height: defaultJson['height'],
      width: defaultJson['width'],
      url: defaultJson['url'],
    );
  }

}

class Thumbnails {
  Default mDefault;
  Medium medium;
  High high;

  Thumbnails({this.mDefault, this.medium, this.high});

  var data = JsonEncoder().convert("");

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'default': mDefault,
        'medium': medium,
        'high': high,
      };

  factory Thumbnails.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> ThumbnailsJson) {
    return Thumbnails(
      mDefault: Default.fromJSON(ThumbnailsJson['default']),
      medium: Medium.fromJSON(ThumbnailsJson['medium']),
      high: High.fromJSON(ThumbnailsJson['high']),
    );
  }
}
```

Now that we have described the format of the JSON we expect it is very easy to parse it:

```
YoutubeResponse parsedResponse =
  YoutubeResponse.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
```

You can then access the items via `parsedResponse.items`, then loop through them and get the title, descriptions etc.

Comment: I added your code but it gives me a [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(188)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'fromJSON' was called on null.

Comment: @CapitanLuzzatto Have you created and imported all models?

Comment: Yes, also I noted that Android Studio didn't recognized the field Id on the Item object and  mPageInfo ond YouTubeResponse object.

Answer (score 1):

To further the answer by @Shaddy (which works) here is my class that calls the network

```
    class VideoNetwork {
  static Future<List<Item>> fetchPost() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(<URL for Youtube Videos>);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      return compute(parseVideos, response.body);
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  static List<Item> parseVideos(String responseBody) {
    YoutubeResponse response =
        YoutubeResponse.fromJSON(json.decode(responseBody));

    return response.items.toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Sh1d0w , was good but it has a lack of content for people who doesnt know so much of flutter itself. I have to say thanks Sh1d0w since you give me the base to create my own code to fetch the data using the youtube url.

I combined his answer using a SearchDelegate in order to show the results , I still need to add the code to show the next/previous page results (youtube only give 50 results by page) but to answer your questions here is the code.
At the end you will be able to get the follow:

publishedAt
channelId
title
description
thumbnails (default, high, medium)
liveBroadcastContent
videoId

If you want any other data from the json, you will need to add what you want in the Class Snippet to be returned and used later.
Since I am using a futureBuilder which give the data in the snapshot.data object, you will need to use this kind of declaration to get each property:

```
snapshot.data[index].title
snapshot.data[index].description
snapshot.data[index].thumbnails.high.url
```

**In the code you will see things like appTheme.text , etc those are just variables of colors, please change them for your colors.
** the functions like sizeBuild() or fontSizeBuild() are functions which I created for my case, you just need to delete those lines and write any number according to your needs

common_youtubeApi.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

class YoutubeResponse{
  //!-1st level parameters of youtube api for playlist
  //!-https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response
  String kind;
  String etag;
  String nextPageToken;
  String prevPageToken;
  String regionCode;
  List<Item> items;
  //change the default values for the obtained values from url
  YoutubeResponse({
    this.kind,
    this.etag,
    this.nextPageToken,
    this.prevPageToken,
    this.regionCode,
    this.items
  });
  //Json decode and make a dart object called Map
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'kind': kind,
    'etag': etag,
    'nextPageToken': nextPageToken,
    'prevPageToken': prevPageToken,
    'regionCode': regionCode,
    'items': items,
  };

  factory YoutubeResponse.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> YoutubeResponseJson){
    var list = YoutubeResponseJson['items'] as List;
    List<Item> itemsList = list.map((i)=> Item.fromJSON(i)).toList();
    return new YoutubeResponse(
      kind: YoutubeResponseJson['kind'],
      etag: YoutubeResponseJson['etag'],
      nextPageToken: YoutubeResponseJson['nextPageToken'],
      prevPageToken: YoutubeResponseJson['prevPageToken'],
      regionCode: YoutubeResponseJson['regionCode'],
      // mPageInfo: pageInfo.fromJSON(YoutubeResponseJson['pageInfo']),
      items: itemsList
    );
  }
}

//---------Create an single video item

class Item{
  String kind;
  String etag;
  String id;
  Snippet snippet;

  Item({
    this.kind, this.etag, this.id, this.snippet
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'kind': kind,
    'etag': etag,
    'id': id,
    'snippet': snippet,
  };
  
  factory Item.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> ItemJson) {
    return Item(
      kind: ItemJson['kind'],
      etag: ItemJson['etag'],
      id: ItemJson['id'],
      snippet: Snippet.fromJSON(ItemJson['snippet']),
    );
  }

}

class Snippet {
  String publishedAt;
  String channelId;
  String title;
  String description;
  Thumbnails thumbnails;
  String channelTitle;
  String liveBroadcastContent;
  String videoId;

  Snippet(
      {this.publishedAt,
      this.channelId,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.thumbnails,
      this.channelTitle,
      this.liveBroadcastContent,
      this.videoId,
      });


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'publishedAt': publishedAt,
        'channelId': channelId,
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'thumbnails': thumbnails,
        'channelTitle': channelTitle,
        'liveBroadcastContent': liveBroadcastContent,
        'videoId': videoId,
      };

  factory Snippet.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> snippetJson) {


    return Snippet(
      publishedAt: snippetJson['publishedAt'],
      channelId: snippetJson['channelId'],
      title: snippetJson['title'],
      description: snippetJson['description'],
      thumbnails:  Thumbnails.fromJSON(snippetJson['thumbnails']) ,
      channelTitle: snippetJson['channelTitle'],
      liveBroadcastContent: snippetJson['liveBroadcastContent'],
      videoId: snippetJson['resourceId']['videoId'],
    );
  }
}

class Medium {
  int height;
  int width;
  String url;

  Medium({this.height, this.width, this.url});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
        'url': url,
      };

  factory Medium.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> MediumJson) {
    return Medium(
      height: MediumJson['height'],
      width: MediumJson['width'],
      url: MediumJson['url'],
    );
  }

}

class High {
  int height;
  int width;
  String url;

  High({this.height, this.width, this.url});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
        'url': url,
      };

  factory High.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> HighJson) {
    return High(
      height: HighJson['height'],
      width: HighJson['width'],
      url: HighJson['url'],
    );
  }

}

class Default {
  int height;
  int width;
  String url;

  Default({this.height, this.width, this.url});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'height': height,
        'width': width,
        'url': url,
      };

  factory Default.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> defaultJson) {
    return Default(
      height: defaultJson['height'],
      width: defaultJson['width'],
      url: defaultJson['url'],
    );
  }

}

class Thumbnails {
  Default mDefault;
  Medium medium;
  High high;

  Thumbnails({this.mDefault, this.medium, this.high});
  
  var data = JsonEncoder().convert("");

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'default': mDefault,
        'medium': medium,
        'high': high,
      };


  factory Thumbnails.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> thumbnailsJson) {
    return Thumbnails(
      mDefault: Default.fromJSON(thumbnailsJson['default']),
      medium: Medium.fromJSON(thumbnailsJson['medium']),
      high: High.fromJSON(thumbnailsJson['high']),
    );
  }
}
```

searchList.dart
files to import:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:denApp/keys/app_keys.dart'; //put your keys always in a different file with gitignore
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart'; //for links in each item
import 'package:denApp/Widgets/common_youtubeAPI.dart'; //here are the models of each data requested in the json to be used here
```

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<List>{
  var nextPageToken;
  var prevPageToken;
  Future<void> _launched;
    //ajax/http request for data
    Future<List<Snippet>> getVideos(http.Client client) async {
      YoutubeResponse parsedResponse;
      final response = await client
          .get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=$youtubeTrickPlaylist&key=$youtubeAPIKEY&maxResults=50');
      List<Snippet> videos = [];
      parsedResponse = YoutubeResponse.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body));
      for(var i=0; i < parsedResponse.items.length; i++ ){
        videos.add(parsedResponse.items[i].snippet);
      }
      this.nextPageToken = parsedResponse.nextPageToken;
      this.prevPageToken = parsedResponse.prevPageToken;
      print(this.nextPageToken);
      print(this.prevPageToken);
      return videos;
  }
  //We use the launcher plugin to manage the click to go to the website, please visit the plugin web for info how to use it

  Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
    print(url);
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        forceWebView: false,
        headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'},
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

//------------------------------------------------------
//--This part is to edit the colors and design of the searchDelegate widget, I have a separated file with the themes, colors which I call using appTheme, so you need to change all those variables with your own colors.

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
      return ThemeData(
        primaryColor: appTheme.text,
        backgroundColor: appTheme.dark,
        bottomAppBarColor: appTheme.dark,
        canvasColor: appTheme.dark,

      );
  }

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//---Here we define how it will works the SearchDelegate and its icons/functions-----------

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
      // ----This is the icon which will delete whatever you write in your searchbar
      return [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () {
        query="";
      },)];
    }
  
    @override
    Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
      // ---- This is the icon which will allow you to close the search delegate going to the back page.
      return IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: (){
        close(context, null);
      });
    }
  
    @override
    Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
      // nothing here
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  
    @override
    Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // This is actually the place where you will do all the work when you receive the data from your future request. Since we are going to build something after we wait for the data, we need to use futureBuilder instead of builder only. In the future propiety you will put the function which will do the request to the api  
    return FutureBuilder<List<Snippet>>(
      future: getVideos(http.Client()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //during the build you need to check the connection state so depending on what is happening you will show something , like a loader if it is waiting state, etc
        switch (snapshot.connectionState){
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('none', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black));
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Text('active', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black));
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          default:
  
            //after checking connection we need to check if we do not got null data from the request
            if(snapshot.data != null){
              var dt = snapshot.data.where((p)=> p.title.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
              return dt.isEmpty? Center(child:Text("There was no results for your query", style: TextStyle(color: appTheme.text))) : ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: dt.length,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if(query.isEmpty){
                      return Card(
                        margin: (index == (dt.length - 1)) ? EdgeInsets.only(top: sizeBuild(context, "height", 5), bottom: sizeBuild(context, "height", 15)) : EdgeInsets.only(top: sizeBuild(context, "height", 5)),
                        color: appTheme.bgLight.withOpacity(.1),
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: appTheme.linkB.withAlpha(30),
                          onTap: () {
                            _launched = _launchInBrowser('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${snapshot.data[index].videoId}');
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width:sizeBuild(context, "width", 140),
                                  child: Image.network("${snapshot.data[index].thumbnails.high.url}", fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  // color: Colors.red,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: sizeBuild(context, "width",10)),
                                  width:sizeBuild(context, "width", 280),
                                  child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].title,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle (
                                          color: appTheme.text,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: fontSizeBuild(context, 'body')
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: sizeBuild(context, "height", 5),
                                    ),
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].description,
                                      maxLines: 3,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle (
                                          color: appTheme.text.withOpacity(.7),
                                          fontSize: fontSizeBuild(context, 'small')
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  
                                  ],
                                ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }else{
                      return Card(
                        margin: (index == (dt.length - 1)) ? EdgeInsets.only(top: sizeBuild(context, "height", 5), bottom: sizeBuild(context, "height", 15)) : EdgeInsets.only(top: sizeBuild(context, "height", 5)),
                        color: appTheme.bgLight.withOpacity(.1),
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: appTheme.linkB.withAlpha(30),
                          onTap: () {
                            _launched = _launchInBrowser('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${snapshot.data[index].videoId}');
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width:sizeBuild(context, "width", 140),
                                  child: Image.network("${snapshot.data[index].thumbnails.high.url}", fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: sizeBuild(context, "width",10)),
                                  width:sizeBuild(context, "width", 280),
                                  child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].title,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle (
                                          color: appTheme.text,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: fontSizeBuild(context, 'body')
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: sizeBuild(context, "height", 20),
                                    ),
                                    Text(snapshot.data[index].description,
                                      maxLines: 5,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle (
                                          color: appTheme.text.withOpacity(.7),
                                          fontSize: fontSizeBuild(context, 'small')
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  
                                  ],
                                ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                 
                );
            }else{
              //this is the widget to give if there is no data
              return Center(child: Text("There was no data from the server", style: TextStyle(color:appTheme.text)));
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code snippet is much more simple than the other answers would imply.

First of all, *your JSON string might be wrong*, you left out a couple of things. You might have also forgotten to unescape the etag values: `"etag": "\\\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/s7-xmHXpuqQxYzDp_wxhm59K4LE\\\"",`. Of course, all of these could be just copying errors.

You *can* create extra classes, and if you want to maintain your code for the long term, you absolutely should. There are code generators that will do most of the work for you. However, you don't *need to* create those humongous classes, just to get out 3 values of that JSON. You also don't need to spin up on a different isolate, that JSON is tiny (for the computer), and you won't notice any performance issues from parsing that.

**There is nothing wrong with the approach you took. It's a simple solution that works, it's great for very simple scripts and apps.**

The only thing is that you forgot that the `items` is a list, so you need to first take the 0th element in that list. After that fix, everything works as expected: `parsed['items'][0]['snippet']['title']`.

You can copy this to dartpad.dev and try it out yourself.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody);
  String title  = parsed['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
  String description  = parsed['items'][0]['snippet']['description'];
  String thumbnail  = parsed['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
  print('title: $title');
  print('description: $description');
  print('thumbnail: $thumbnail');
}

const responseBody = '''{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\\\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/s7-xmHXpuqQxYzDp_wxhm59K4LE\\\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "\\\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/pajQ7iBy-7A0V_owifxkw-Kbw-Y\\\"",
      "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T23:12:38.000Z",
        "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
        "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
        "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}''';
```